# Ho to access to the class-level instance variable in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, metaprogramming

I want to access the attr declared in the class scope from the instance. I want to add some helper methods to the class that other classes can use it, like all methods in the active record for example `validates` and others. Is this possible to do ?

```
class SomeClass
 def initialize()
 end

 def do_something
   helper_methods
   # hot ot acces here to the @helper_methods class-level instance variable
 end

 class << self
   attr_accessor :helper_methods

   def some_helper_method(name, &block)
     add_helper_method(name, &block)
   end

   def add_helper_method(name, options = {}, &block)
     @helper_methods ||= {}
     @helper_methods[name] = {
       attr_or_block: block_given? ? block : name,
       options: options,
     }
   end
 end
end

class SecondClass < SomeClass
 some_helper_method :name
end

SecondClass.new.do_something
# should retunrs [:name]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would expect

```
def do_something
  self.class.helper_methods
end
```

to return the value from the class variable.

Comment: Additionally if you want to be able to call helper_methods as an instance method you can use `delegate :helper_methods, to: :class` or just declare a good old instance method.